# Newbie about relation in EFCodeFirst

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

What is difference between below code?

```
 public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Gener> Gener { get; set; }
}

public class Gener
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Albumcontext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Gener> Geners { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
 public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Gener Gener { get; set; }
}

public class Gener
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Albumcontext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Gener> Geners { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

i know for relation 2 entity must using code no.2 but how to use List<> or Collection<>?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Neither make sense, Album/Genre is a N:N kind of relationship (Genres can be linked to many Albums, and an Album can span more Genres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first block you in `Album` class you create a property `Gener`, that is a list of `Gener` objects - this means you want one `Album` to have many `Geners`:

```
public List<Gener> Gener { get; set; }
```

In secound block in the same class you have a property `Gener` that is of type `Gener`, so it points to only one object of class `Gener`. This means you want `Album` to have one `Gener`.

```
public Gener Gener { get; set; }
```

BTW, you have a typo in a class name - I think you wanted Genre, not Gener.

**EDIT:**

To learn more about defining relationships in Entity Framework, check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx).

Comment: @MeysamSavameri As Alex pointed out [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812231/newbie-about-relation-in-efcodefirst/14812356#comment20747714_14812231) Album-Genre relationship is many-to-many - one album can have many genres defined (you know that it's hard to tell that a band plays only one genre sometimes) and one genre can have many albums of course.

Check my updated answer, I added link to article about relationships there.

Answer (score 1):

First one creates relation "One `Album` can have many `Genres`", second creates "One `Album` can have only one `Genre` but one `Genre` may be linked with many `Albums`".

Looking at your example, you would want to have relation many-to-many, `Album` may have one or many `Genres` and `Genre` may be linked with one or many `Albums`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example there is a many to one relationship between `Album` and `Gener`. Since each `Gener` is linked to only one `Album`,  `Gener` get the foreign key to `Album`.

In the second its just a one to one relationship and you have a reference to a `Gener` object in your `Album` model, so `Album` gets the foreign key to `Gener`.